# Execute code after ALL event listeners callback were executed

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I add event listeners to my input:

```
['input', 'keypress', 'keyup', 'keydown'].forEach(eventName => {
    document.getElementById('my-input').addEventListener(eventName, (e) => {
      // handle eventName for input
   });
});
```

I want to execute some code after callbacks for all registered events are executed.
It is possible? If yes, please explain how to do that

**EDIT:**

But I don't know which events will be triggered.
For example user focused input, and then pressed Esc, in this case only keyup and keydown events will be triggered.

**EDIT 2:**
My task is to handle user interactions on the page.
I should handle interactions by user and after one particular interaction(focus on field, input of character, keystroke), and after all callbacks for this interaction happened I should execute some code.

1. User focuses inout => focus callback is executed
2. should execute some code
3. User presses Esc => keydown and keyup callbacks are executed
4. should execute some code
5. User enters symbol in field => input, keypress, keyup, keydown callbacks are executed
6. should execute some code

Comment: @Mamun What I didn't try?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `setTimeout` to run a function immediately after all synchronous events are completed:

```js
let timeout;
['input', 'keypress', 'keyup', 'keydown']
  .forEach(eventName => {
    document.getElementById('my-input').addEventListener(eventName, (e) => {
      // handle eventName for input
      console.log(eventName + ' triggered');
      if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
      timeout = setTimeout(afterEvents);
    });
  });
function afterEvents() {
  console.log('all event listeners have been triggered');
}
```

```html
<input id="my-input">
```

Comment: I will update my question(I asked very simplified version of my needs)

Comment: @Yuriy I don't get the difference - whether or not the user presses `esc` or not after focusing on the input field won't have an effect on the other events triggered on the field - as it works in the snippet.

Comment: @Yuriy It kind of sounds like you're trying to figure out how to run something after *any* callback is run, not after *all* callbacks are run, which is a *very* different question

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to run something after **all** callbacks are run which are triggered by **one** user interaction

Comment: @Yuriy See edit. (try to post clear questions *before* people start answering)

Comment: Sorry, it was my fault. But your snippet doesn't work as expected, I just run it with `Run code snippet` button

Comment: I focused input, pressed Esc, `all event listeners have been triggered` are logged twice, but it should be logged only once

Comment: @Yuriy The `keydown` event triggers *separately* from the `keyup` event - unlike the combination of `keydown`, `keypress`, and `input` events (which trigger all at once when a key is pressed), `keydown` and `keyup` do not occur at the same time. Often there's only a few ms difference, but it *can* be as long as the user holds the key down - it can't be synchronous.